# How to close AdSense account with my unknown email address

Tags: google-account, google-adsense

I am trying to get an approval on Google AdSense account through my email address example@gmail.com but it keeps disapproving due to having another unknown gmail account already have Google AdSense. The email address is ta95...@gmail.com and I don't remember it's mine.

Please advise how to remove it completely?

Comment: I have the same exact issue